# How to allow for a fallback on empty values in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

The field object has three properties: `label`, `name`, and `value`

I need to set the `<option>` text equal to the `label` property unless it's null.  If it's null, then I need to use the `name` property for the text. If that's empty, I need to fallback to use the `value` property for the text.  How can I make this cascade so that I don't have "undefined" for the text if the property is null?

```
<select ng-model="c.field" ng-options="f.label for f in c.fields">
    <option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? `ng-options="(f.label || f.name || f.value) for f in c.fields"`

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("controller", function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.fields = [
    {
      label: "label",
      name: "name",
      value: "value"
    },
    {
      label: null,
      name: "name",
      value: "value"
    },
    {
      name: "",
      value: "value"
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller as c">
  <select ng-model="c.field" ng-options="(f.label || f.name || f.value) for f in c.fields">
    <option value="">-- Select an Option --</option>
  </select>
  
  Selected field: {{c.field | json}}
</div>
```

Comment: ah - so simple!  Thanks!